# I am getting errors when I try to install rails for the first time. I am on macOS High Sierra

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
jeffreys-air:~ Jeffrey$ gem install rails
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0 directory.
```

I have no idea what this means. Someone please explain

Comment: Have you installed ruby using rbenv?

Answer (score 0):

Use gem update --system to upgrade the Ruby gem manager:

```
$ gem update --system
```

Add this to your **.bash_profile**

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```